# Reply (to whom) to reply in Discussion Board

Tags: sharepoint-server, discussion-board

I need to clone a whole available discussion board (DB) to another DB, and managed to copy the topics with their replies inside successfully. However, the replies do not show the "In response to sb's comment", so I wonder if there is a specific ways to copy that property too. Thanks a ton.